# Photoswipe capture swipe event

Tags: jquery, photoswipe

How do I capture a swipe event in photoswipe?

I tried the following...

```
var pSwipe = window.Code.PhotoSwipe.attach($(arrGallery), options);
pSwipe.show(0);
pSwipe.addEventHandler(window.Code.PhotoSwipe.ActionTypes.swipeLeft, function (e) {
    alert('swipe left');
});
```

but it doesn't catch the event?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

```
var pSwipe = window.Code.PhotoSwipe.attach($(arrGallery), options);
pSwipe.show(0);
pSwipe.addEventHandler(window.Code.PhotoSwipe.EventTypes.onTouch, function (e) {
    switch (e.action) {
        case 'swipeDown':
            alert('you swiped down');
            break;
        case 'swipeUp':
            alert('you swiped up');
            break;
     }
});
```